# PHP Add Missing Date(s) to array (stdClass Object)

Tags: php, arrays, date, datetime

i have an array with some employee data and i need to fill the gap for missing dates, i tried but i cannot get it to fill in the missing dates

from an search range: eg. FROM 2015-10-25 to 2015-10-26
current result:

```
   [92] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [DT] => 2015-10-26
                    [CheckIn] => Array
                        (
                            [t] => 15:52
                            [label] => success
                        )

                    [CheckOut] => Array
                        (
                            [t] => 19:41
                            [label] => danger
                        )

                    [Hours] => 3.82
                )

    [56] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [DT] => 2015-10-25
                    [CheckIn] => Array
                        (
                            [t] => 12:05
                            [label] => danger
                        )

                    [CheckOut] => Array
                        (
                            [t] => 20:09
                            [label] => danger
                        )

                    [Hours] => 8.07
                ),

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [DT] => 2015-10-26
                    [CheckIn] => Array
                        (
                            [t] => 12:05
                            [label] => danger
                        )

                    [CheckOut] => Array
                        (
                            [t] => 20:09
                            [label] => danger
                        )

                    [Hours] => 8.07
                )

        )
```

as you can see the first one is missing 25th, i need need an loop to fill in the missing date.

should look like this:

```
   [92] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [DT] => 2015-10-25
                    [CheckIn] => Array
                        (
                            [t] => NCO
                            [label] => danger
                        )

                    [CheckOut] => Array
                        (
                            [t] => NCO
                            [label] => danger
                        )

                    [Hours] => 3.82
                ),
            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [DT] => 2015-10-26
                    [CheckIn] => Array
                        (
                            [t] => 15:52
                            [label] => success
                        )

                    [CheckOut] => Array
                        (
                            [t] => 19:41
                            [label] => danger
                        )

                    [Hours] => 3.82
                )

    [56] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [DT] => 2015-10-25
                    [CheckIn] => Array
                        (
                            [t] => 12:05
                            [label] => danger
                        )

                    [CheckOut] => Array
                        (
                            [t] => 20:09
                            [label] => danger
                        )

                    [Hours] => 8.07
                ),

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [DT] => 2015-10-26
                    [CheckIn] => Array
                        (
                            [t] => 12:05
                            [label] => danger
                        )

                    [CheckOut] => Array
                        (
                            [t] => 20:09
                            [label] => danger
                        )

                    [Hours] => 8.07
                )

        )
```

current loop, maybe you can help me implement something withing this:

```
//this is to join each user by their id
    $result = array();
foreach ($r['d'] as $data) {
  $id = $data->badgenumber;
  if (isset($result[$id])) {
     $result[$id][] = $data;
  } else {
     $result[$id] = array($data);
  }
  $date = $data->DT;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: I don't see any missing dates (`DT`).

Comment: 2015-10-25 is missing from the result, i added it for illustration reasons.

**DT** 2015-10-25 is missing from actual result.

Comment: So if you are iterating through your results, can you use `isset()` or `empty()`? `if(empty($data->DT)){ // do a thing }`

Comment: **DT** date, or data does not exist. this is employee report if they did not come into work there will be no dates showing up i have to make missing dates for the report, and add some data to it E.G.. Absent/OffSick..

Comment: So it sounds like you need a preset list of days the user was scheduled to work. Example: 10/25, 10/26, 10/27, 10/28. If the user was absent on the 25th, `$data->DT` would not exist for that specific day, correct? Sounds like you need to iterate your scheduled list to check if data exists for specific days.

Comment: The are no schedule for work  but each users should work 6 days a week except Friday its up-to them,

Comment: If there is no schedule, then use the days of the search range.